# Heroku ACM SSL works for .herokuapp.com but not real domain

Tags: ssl, heroku, lets-encrypt

I've followed the guide [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/automated-certificate-management) for SSL to be automatically configured on my site. It does have the certificate when I visit mysite.herokuapp.com. When I go to my real domain, mysite.com, the site is completely reachable but doesn't seem to have the certificate. I'm pointing the DNS entry to the exact result of 'heroku domains'; note that this entry has not changed since I added SSL it seems. It ends in a .herokudns.com not .herokuapp.com or herokussl.com like I've seen in some of the previous answers on Stack Overflow. I assume that Heroku recently changed this requirement for setup.

I've already waited a few hours. I assume I must be doing something wrong, but I think I've followed the guide correctly, and there are so few steps, so I'm at a loss...

Comment: "When I go to my real domain, mysite.com, the site is completely reachable but doesn't seem to have the certificate." It might be that this _does_ work, but your application isn't redirecting HTTP to HTTPS. If you manually type the HTTPS URL into your browser does the site load?

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly it! I'm very surprised that it does redirect me for mysite.herokuapp.com then... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris pointed out in the comments, the solution was heroku is doing something which prevents normal redirection of http to https. This post is very helpful for node js:

https://jaketrent.com/post/https-redirect-node-heroku/